# jQuery before() / after() not working properly with HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I crossed uppon a weird problem. I have a list with links like so:

```
<ul class="sub-navigation">
    <li><a href="">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="">c</a></li>
    <li><a href="">d</a></li>
    <li><a href="">e</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I want to do is make jQuery split the list in two by inserting closing and then opening tags after, say, the third list item. So I go like so:

```
$('.sub-navigation li').eq(2).after('google');
```

It properly inserts the text and I get:

```
<ul class="sub-navigation">
    <li><a href="">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="">c</a></li>google
    <li><a href="">d</a></li>
    <li><a href="">e</a></li>
</ul>
```

which is correct, but when I try to insert the actual tags like so:

```
$('.sub-navigation li').eq(2).after('</ul><ul class="sub-navigation">');
```

it reverses them o_O

```
<ul class="sub-navigation">
    <li><a href="">a</a></li>
    <li><a href="">b</a></li>
    <li><a href="">c</a></li><ul class="sub-navigation"></ul>
    <li><a href="">d</a></li>
    <li><a href="">e</a></li>
</ul>
```

Why is that so? Can't `before()` just insert the raw HTML I gave it?
If I try to insert just `</ul>` it dissapears...

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you *really* want to do? Inserting a tag with syntax error is not a good idea, and it makes it not clear what you are trying to achieve.  Also, almost all browser *try* to correct *automagically* syntax error in HTML.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery methods such as `before()` and `after()` manipulate the browser's DOM tree.
The DOM holds *complete* HTML elements.  You can't put in half of a tag.

Instead, you need to manipulate entire tags:

```
$('.sub-navigation li:eq(2)').nextAll().remove().appendTo(
    $('<ul class="sub-navigation">').insertAfter($('.sub-navigation'))
)
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! I found my problem had a more elegant solution using CSS, but this is quite helpful anyway!

Answer (score 0):

It is bad to insert HTML tags with syntax error, because almost all web browser *will try* to *automagically* fix it, that's the reason when you try to insert `<ul/>` which is a bad syntax, doesn't works as expected.

Answering your question, you can do the following:

```
// Select all li.
var allLis = $('ul.sub-navigation li');
// Get mid index.
var mid = Math.floor(allLis.length / 2);
// Filter li's before mid index.
var lis = allLis.filter(':lt(' + mid + ')');
// Create new ul.
var ul = $('<ul />');
// Append first li's
ul.append(lis);
// Then put the new ul before the current ul.
$('ul').before(ul);
```

You can [see a working on example with your markup in this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mariuzzo/LJ8AB/).

Answer (score 0):

you can Use jquery's [remove](http://api.jquery.com/remove/) / [detach](http://api.jquery.com/detach/) ( use detach if you want to retain bound events on the element ) and then attach it to a newly created ul

Eg:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
    $('.sub-navigation').after($('<ul class="sub-navigation"></ul>').append($('.sub-navigation li:gt(2)').remove()));
});
```

example code on [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/azy777/PemWS/2/)